# Not able to sync project with Gradle files (Re-download dependencies and sync project Gradle Problem)

Tags: android, gradle

***After Android Studio Upgrade it shows following error when sync project with gradle files:***

**ERROR: Failed to open zip file.**
Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)

**Project Build Gradle**

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.2'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**Gradle-wrapper properties**

```
#Fri Apr 17 20:10:05 IST 2020
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zip
```

*----Use graddle from is set to gradle-wrapper-properties file*

*----Android Gradle Plug in version is 3.6.2
Gradle version is 5.6.4*

Changed gradle version also still showing error

Event log

```
9:03 PM Gradle sync failed: Cause: error in opening zip file
                Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (16 m 50 s 157 ms)

9:03 PM Android Studio is using the following JDK location when running Gradle:
                I:\Android\android-studio-ide-192.6308749-windows32_17-4-2020\android-studio\jre
                Using different JDK locations on different processes might cause Gradle to
                spawn multiple daemons, for example, by executing Gradle tasks from a terminal
                while using Android Studio.
                More info...
                Select a JDK from the File System
                Do not show this warning again
```